# No Resources window .Net Core WPF project in Microsoft Blend 2019

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, .net-core, blend

I am having an issue with Blend for Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11.3. When I create a .Net Framework project I can access the Resource Window via the "View" toolbar at the top.

[image: Image of the view menu in .Net Framework project]

However I seem to be unable to access the same window when the project is using .Net Core.

[image: Image of the view menu in .Net Coreproject]

I am having trouble figuring out where and why the Resources window might be hidden? I want this functionality to make it easier to apply styles using the interface and just drag&dropping styles vs writing them out in xaml.

Comment: There isn't one when using a non-Blend interface. You should have some resource files from your Blend. Theses will be apparent in the solution explorer. You must access the XAML directly in VS, but you could still design using Blend then switch to VS for the coding.

Comment: I am using the same version of Blend both for .Net Core and .Net Framework apps.  The problem is that the "View" menu is different depending on the type of project (Core vs Framework) and I cannot access the thing I need (Resources Window) in Core app.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the steps below to display the Resources Window menu.

1. Click `Customize...` under the `Tools` menu.
2. Click `Commands` and select `Menu bar` as `View`.

[image]

3. Click `Add Command...` ->Select `View` and `Resources Window` on the Add Command page and click OK.

[image]

4. Click Close on the Customize page.

[image]

Then you could see the Resources Window under the View menu.

[image]

Comment: Hi,@user2396632.May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any others questions.

Comment: the command appears but not the window / tab